# Basic exponential regression

Tags: statistics, exponential-function, regression, linear-regression

***Background:***

I'm attempting to learn about basic statistics for the infrastructure asset management industry:

- *[Basic math explanation (related to estimating linear regression with no intercept)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566552/basic-math-explanation-related-to-estimating-linear-regression-with-no-intercep)*

---

**Problem:**

I would like to learn how to generate an exponential regression equation for road condition data, just like it was done for me here:

- [Development of a Flexible Framework for Deterioration Modelling in Infrastructure Asset Management](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/33410/1/Ens_Abra_M_201211_MASc_thesis.pdf)
- Hint: Skip to page 53 (the printed page number, not the PDF page number)

In other words, I want to learn how to generate an exponential regression equation, so I can eventually update the coefficient in the existing model (on the full/real dataset).

---

**My soloution (mock data):**

I've mocked up a sample dataset here:

```
+--------------+---------------+
|    X (AGE)   | Y (CONDITION) |
+--------------+---------------+
|       0      |       20      |
|       1      |       20      |
|       2      |       20      |
|       3      |       20      |
|       4      |       20      |
|       5      |       20      |
|       6      |       18      |
|       7      |       18      |
|       8      |       18      |
|       9      |       18      |
|       10     |       16      |
|       11     |       16      |
|       12     |       14      |
|       13     |       14      |
|       14     |       12      |
|       15     |       12      |
|       16     |       10      |
|       17     |        8      |
|       18     |        6      |
|       19     |        4      |
|       20     |        2      |
+--------------+---------------+
```

---

Steps in Excel:

Column C: Convert `Y` to be more linear using the natural logarithm function

Column D: Calculate a straight line that best fits the data, and then return an array that describes the line (using the LINEST function).

Column E: Generate a trend-line on D, and use the coefficient from that trend-line to create an exponential regression equation: **`=21-exp(0.14723*x)`**

[image]
[image]

---

**Question:**

How successful was I? Was my approach mathematically correct?

---

**Related:**

- [Normal equation in Excel (statistics)](https://superuser.com/questions/1697101/normal-equation-in-excel-statistics)
- [Tune an exponential regression estimate using calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352984/tune-an-exponential-regression-estimate-using-calculus)
- [Options for tuning exponential regression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353392/options-for-tuning-exponential-regression)
- [Mimic Excel Solver nonlinear regression? (to reduce ESS of exponential regression)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353481/mimic-excel-solver-nonlinear-regression-to-reduce-ess-of-exponential-regressio)
- [Excel: data table (hit and trial)](https://superuser.com/a/1697485/712431)

Comment: Is this clear ? Tell if it is not.

Comment: This is a weird model. Does it mean that a road only lives for 21 years ? Also, there's a single parameter to estimate, hence you don't need a bivariate regression , just a single parameter estimator (expectation).

Comment: @Woody3 Good points. The data is just dummy data for learning purposes. A road would normally live for around 80 years. And good call on the bivariate regression not being necessary. I think I can simply do linear regression using $ln(21-y)$. I can do that using a trendline in Excel. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUqzd.png Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to fit the model
$$y=21-e^{a x}\tag 1$$
For sure, you can have an extimate writing
$$21-y=e^{a x}\implies \log(21-y)=ax\implies z=a x\tag 2$$ and a preliminary linear regression gives $a=0.147233$ (just as you did).

In fact, you do not need to use regression since you can get $a$ directly from the normal equation
$$a=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iz_i } { \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 }=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log(21-y_i)} { \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 }$$

But this is only the preliminary step since what is measured is $y$ and not $\log(21-y)$. So, you need to continue with a nonlinear regression using this estimate. This would lead to $a=0.149140$.

Let us compare the results for $y$ using both models
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 x & y & (2) & (1) \\
 0 & 20 & 20.0000 & 20.0000 \\
 1 & 20 & 19.8414 & 19.8392 \\
 2 & 20 & 19.6576 & 19.6525 \\
 3 & 20 & 19.4447 & 19.4357 \\
 4 & 20 & 19.1979 & 19.1841 \\
 5 & 20 & 18.9121 & 18.8921 \\
 6 & 18 & 18.5809 & 18.5531 \\
 7 & 18 & 18.1972 & 18.1595 \\
 8 & 18 & 17.7526 & 17.7027 \\
 9 & 18 & 17.2374 & 17.1723 \\
 10 & 16 & 16.6406 & 16.5567 \\
 11 & 16 & 15.9491 & 15.8421 \\
 12 & 14 & 15.1479 & 15.0125 \\
 13 & 14 & 14.2196 & 14.0495 \\
 14 & 12 & 13.1441 & 12.9316 \\
 15 & 12 & 11.8980 & 11.6339 \\
 16 & 10 & 10.4542 & 10.1275 \\
 17 & 8 & 8.78136 & 8.37881 \\
 18 & 6 & 6.84319 & 6.34887 \\
 19 & 4 & 4.59758 & 3.99245 \\
 20 & 2 & 1.99576 & 1.25704
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using model $(2)$ and back to the $y$'s, the sum of squares is $8.28$ while using model $(1)$ lead to a sum of squares equal to $6.66$ which is quite better.

Moreover, it is interesting to look at the statistics.

For model $(2)$, we have
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.147233 & 0.005034 & \{0.136698,0.157769\} \\
\end{array}$$ while for model $(1)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.149140 & 0.000873 & \{0.147312,0.150967\} \\
\end{array}$$ showing that, using the "true" model, the standard error is basically divided by a factor of almost $6$.

If you do not want to use nonlinear regression, you could use Excel to solve for $a$ the equation
$$f(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n e^{ax_i}\left(21-e^{ax_i}-y_i \right)=0$$ strating from the preliminary guess. Even graphing the function could be sufficient.

For solving the equation, you could also use Newton method
$$f'(a)=a\sum_{i=1}^n e^{ax_i}\left(21-2e^{ax_i}-y_i \right)$$ and use
$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)}$$ using for $a_0$ the value obtained from the preliminary step.

For your problem, Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & 0.1472330000 \\
 1 & 0.1492437955 \\
 2 & 0.1491401458 \\
 3 & 0.1491398530
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we consider the data set outside its specific context, we could have obtained a better fit using
$$y=a-b\, e^{cx}\tag 3$$ which leads to a sum of squares equal to $4.97$ with the following parameters
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 22.1098 & 0.5276 & \{20.9968,23.2229\} \\
 b & 1.57255 & 0.3101 & \{0.91830,2.22680\} \\
 c & 0.12823 & 0.0092 & \{0.10875,0.14771\} \\
\end{array}$$ leading to the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & y & (3) \\
 0 & 20 & 20.5373 \\
 1 & 20 & 20.3221 \\
 2 & 20 & 20.0775 \\
 3 & 20 & 19.7995 \\
 4 & 20 & 19.4834 \\
 5 & 20 & 19.1241 \\
 6 & 18 & 18.7156 \\
 7 & 18 & 18.2513 \\
 8 & 18 & 17.7234 \\
 9 & 18 & 17.1233 \\
 10 & 16 & 16.4410 \\
 11 & 16 & 15.6655 \\
 12 & 14 & 14.7838 \\
 13 & 14 & 13.7816 \\
 14 & 12 & 12.6422 \\
 15 & 12 & 11.3469 \\
 16 & 10 & 9.87440 \\
 17 & 8 & 8.20046 \\
 18 & 6 & 6.29750 \\
 19 & 4 & 4.13420 \\
 20 & 2 & 1.67494
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @Wilson. Basically you did most of it by yourself. For the remaing, code in Excel the last recurrence relation. That's all. It is very simple. Tell me what you do not understand. Cheers.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this?: `But this is only the preliminary step since what is measured is y and not log(21−y). So, you need to continue with a nonlinear regression using this estimate. This would lead to a=0.149140.` Where did `0.149140` come from?

Comment: @Wilson. The two models are not the same; so the parameters are not identical (except if the model was perfect and no error at all in the $y$'s. The first step (using logarithms) allows a qucik and easy *estimate* of $a$. Now, using model $(1)$, you have to tune it for final solution. This is given by the nonlinear regression.

Comment: @Wilson. You are welcome ! I would prefer *Basic exponential regression*

Comment: Regarding, *"So, you need to continue with a nonlinear regression using this estimate."* How do you recommend I go about doing the nonlinear regression?

Comment: I have posted an answer on SuperUser to your question about implementing the Normal Equations which shows how to undertake the nonlinear regression in Excel using a search procedure. It agrees with the results @Claude provides (including the 0.149140), though is less extensive as I suspect he is using a statistical package which provides a broader range of outputs. Between the two you should be able to develop your understanding.